# what variable name to use

Tags: ios, iboutlet

In my header file I have:

```
IBOutlet UITextField * _userNameOrEmail; 
IBOutlet UITextField * _password; 



@property (retain) IBOutlet UITextField * userNameOrEmail;
@property (retain) IBOutlet UITextField * password;
```

In my implementation I have:

```
@synthesize userNameOrEmail=_userNameOrEmail, password=_password;
```

When I go into my nib file, I can drag the UITextField and it gives me options for both _userNameOrEmail and userNameOrEmail

which one should I use?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With this line

```
@synthesize userNameOrEmail=_userNameOrEmail
```

you are declaring a property userNameOrEmail with the backing iVar _userNameOrEmail. You do **NOT** need to do another declaration like this:

```
IBOutlet UITextField * _userNameOrEmail; 
IBOutlet UITextField * _password;
```

You can now acces the backing iVar via `_userNameOrEmail =` or the property via `self.userNameOrEmail =`. I would recommend that you use the property because you can access the variable via other classes if needed, it will manage memory for you, you can use the dot notation....

Answer (score 0):

Current suggested Objective-C 2.0 practice is to use the same name for the ivar as the property. You can optionally assign a different ivar in the `@property` declaration, but the fact that by default, synthesized accessors for a property will access the ivar with the same name as the property indicates that's the pattern they expect you to follow.

The naming convention for the instance variable prefixed by _ is now clearly stated by Apple in the "[Coding Guidelines for Cocoa](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CodingGuidelines/Articles/NamingIvarsAndTypes.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001284-BAJGIIJE)", after the revision of 2012-02-16, with its reason.

> Make sure the name of the instance variable concisely describes the attribute stored. Usually, you should not access instance variables directly, instead you should use accessor methods (you do access instance variables directly in init and dealloc methods). To help to signal this, prefix instance variable names with an underscore (_) ex -